# Big O analysis of sorting each string in an array of strings, and then sorting that array of string

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I've been reading Cracking the Coding Interview, and I am a bit confused as to the explanation the author gives with regards to a particular example. In the book, the author explains that we have an array of strings (these arrays I made up and do not appear on the book):

```
["abc", "a", "dcglkjsl"];
```

The first task of this algorithm is to sort each string, to be left with:

```
["abc","a","cdgjklls"];
```

And then sort the original array, something like this:

```
["a", "abc", "cdgjklls"];
```

now, the author goes on to analyze the algorithm part by part, to arrive at a solution of O(a * s(log a + log s)) where a is the length of the array and s is the length of the longest string.

Why is sorting each individual string's complexity O(s log s)? I can't seem to wrap my head around that. The author says it's a blatantly obvious conclusion but I don't understand why. I feel that if I understand this crucial bit of information, I'll be able to understand how the author arrived at the final solution above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is sorting each individual string's complexity O(s log s)?

If you choose a `std:map` or a `balanced Binary Search Tree`to populate each of the character of string, then it would take `O(s log s)` to fill the map or BST. `log s` is the depth of the tree.